# uglify merging multi js files into single js file with minified

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs

Here i am with new task where combining multiple file js into single js file and minify the js.

Steps i made,

1. Installed nodeJS in my local machine
2. checked node and npm is working
3. Installed "uglify-js" by "npm install uglify-js " and installed

But i have minified single js with below code:

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
var fs = require('fs');

var result = UglifyJS.minify('site.js', {
    mangle: true,
    compress: {
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        conditionals: true,
        booleans: true,
        unused: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        drop_console: true
    }
});

fs.writeFileSync('site.min.js', result.code);
```

This working perfectly to me.

But ,

i have site1.js,site2.js and site3.js
this should be converted into single minified file (eg.files.min.js)

Comment: uglifyjs --compress --mangle --output master.min.js --  site1.js,site2.js,site3.js.........This working correctly via cli

Comment: But i want that to be exceuted like above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it an array of filenames

```
var result = UglifyJS.minify([ "file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.js" ]);
```

Doc: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#the-simple-way

Comment: just like you did before? Passing an array is an optional replacement for passing the string as the first argument, rest of the signature stays the same.